# React useNavigate navigate("/") not working (+d3.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

Im implementing a basic login which checks wether a user is in a list or not, if it is, then put the username into localStorage and then redirect to ("/") based on the console.log it sais that it got redirected but it doesnt actually redirect:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login({ fakeData }) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Submitting login form');
        console.log('Username: ' + username);

        // Check if user with entered username exists
        const userExists = fakeData.users.find((user) => user.username === username);

        if (userExists) {
            console.log('User exists. Redirecting to /');
            localStorage.setItem('loggedInUser', username); // Set username in localStorage

            navigate('/');
        } else {
            // Clear username
            setUsername('');
            console.log('User does not exist.');
            // Handle invalid username case (display error message, etc.)
        }
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
            <div style={{ padding: '1rem', border: '1px solid black', borderRadius: '8px', width: '300px' }}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div style={{ marginBottom: '1rem', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <label htmlFor="username" style={{ marginRight: '0.5rem' }}>
                            Username:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="username"
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

[image]

as you see it gets printed out, but it still stays on /login

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import DifficultyComparison from "./components/comparisons/DifficultyComparison";
import RestrictionComparison from "./components/comparisons/RestrictionComparison";
import EnvironmentComparison from "./components/comparisons/EnvironmentComparison";
import CurrentContributionComparison from "./components/comparisons/CurrentContributionComparison";
import AllowsMeToComparison from "./components/comparisons/AllowsMeToComparison";
import SustainableDevelopmentComparison from "./components/comparisons/SustainableDevelopmentComparison";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import Login from "./components/Login";


const App = () => {
    const [fakeData, setFakeData] = useState({
        //Unnecessarly Long js object
    });
    const [selectedOption1, setSelectedOption1] = useState('Max Mustermann');
    const [selectedOption2, setSelectedOption2] = useState('Challenge');
    const [selectedOption3, setSelectedOption3] = useState([]);
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser');

    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                {!loggedInUser && <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/login"/>}/>}
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login fakeData={fakeData}/>}/>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <Dashboard
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/difficulty"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <DifficultyComparison
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/restriction"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <RestrictionComparison
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/environment"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <EnvironmentComparison
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/currentcontribution"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <CurrentContributionComparison
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/allowsmeto"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <AllowsMeToComparison
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/sustainabledevelopment"
                    element={
                        loggedInUser ? (
                            <SustainableDevelopmentComparison
                                fakeData={fakeData}
                                selectedOption1={selectedOption1}
                                setSelectedOption1={setSelectedOption1}
                                selectedOption2={selectedOption2}
                                setSelectedOption2={setSelectedOption2}
                                selectedOption3={selectedOption3}
                                setSelectedOption3={setSelectedOption3}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Navigate to="/login"/>
                        )
                    }
                />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

it should also be said that in the website i did use d3.js which also changes the virtual dom and im doing refreshes here and there to update charts and such, so what i think happened is that it redirects, but there kinda is a conflict with the dom or so and it reloads? idk ill provide
a code sample aswell:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

function CommitmentsBar({
                            data,
                            width,
                            height,
                            fakeData,
                            selectedOption1,
                            selectedOption2,
                            selectedOption3,
                            setSelectedOption1,
                            setSelectedOption2,
                            setSelectedOption3
                        }) {

    let eingeloeste = [];


    const cId = fakeData.commitments.filter(commitment => commitment.commitmentname === selectedOption2)[0].commitmentid;

    if (cId >= 0) {
        const cId = fakeData.commitments.filter(commitment => commitment.commitmentname === selectedOption2)[0].commitmentid;
        selectedOption3.map(option => {
            const groupOfUsers = fakeData.groups.filter(group => group.groupname === option)[0].users;
            const diariesFromCiD = fakeData.diary.filter(diary => diary.commitmentid === cId);
            const selectedDiaries = diariesFromCiD.filter(diary => groupOfUsers.includes(diary.userid));
            const eingeloest = selectedDiaries.map(diary => diary.eingeloest);
            const sum = eingeloest.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            const avg = sum / groupOfUsers.length || 0;
            eingeloeste.push(avg);
            return avg;
        });
    }

    data = eingeloeste.length > 0 ? eingeloeste : [];
    const groups = selectedOption3
    const colors = ["#85B3B7"];

    const svgRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style('overflow', 'visible');

        const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map((value, index) => index))
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(0.5);

        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 28])
            .range([height, 0]);

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            .tickFormat((value, index) => groups[index])
            .tickSize(0);

        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
            .ticks(6)
            .tickValues([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 28]);

        svg.selectAll('g').remove();

        svg.append('g')
            .call(xAxis)
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
            .selectAll('text')
            .style('font-size', '16px');

        svg.append('g')
            .call(yAxis)
            .selectAll('text')
            .style('fill', 'black')
            .style('font-size', '16px');

        const horizontalLines = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSize(-width)
            .tickFormat('')
            .tickSizeOuter(0);

        svg.append('g')
            .call(horizontalLines)
            .attr('class', 'horizontal-lines')
            .selectAll('.tick line')
            .attr('stroke', 'lightgrey')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .attr('stroke-dasharray', '4 4');

        const group = svg.selectAll('.group')
            .data(data)
            .join('g')
            .attr('class', 'group');

        group.append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('x', (value, index) => xScale(index))
            .attr('y', yScale)
            .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('height', value => height - yScale(value))
            .attr('fill', '#85B3B7');

        group.each(function (d, i) {
            if (i % 4 === 3) {
                // Append a line and text to every 4th group
                const groupIndex = Math.floor(i / 4);
                d3.select(this)
                    .append('line')
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .attr('x1', xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2 + 15)
                    .attr('y1', yScale(28))
                    .attr('x2', xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2 + 15)
                    .attr('y2', yScale(28) - 30)
                    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
                    .attr('stroke-width', 1);

                d3.select(this)
                    .append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'group-label')
                    .attr('x', xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2 + 15)
                    .attr('y', yScale(28) - 35)
                    .text(`Klasse ${groupIndex + 1}`)
                    .style('font-size', '12px')
                    .style('text-anchor', 'middle');
            }
        });

        const legendWidth = 80 * colors.length;
        const legend = svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(${(width - legendWidth) / 2}, ${height - 20})`);

        legend.selectAll('.legend-item')
            .data(colors)
            .join('g')
            .attr('class', 'legend-item')
            .attr('transform', (value, index) => `translate(${index * 80}, 0)`)
            .call(g => {
                g.append('rect')
                    .attr('x', 0)
                    .attr('y', -height)
                    .attr('width', 15)
                    .attr('height', 15)
                    .attr('fill', value => value);
                g.append('text')
                    .attr('x', 20)
                    .attr('y', -height + 13)
                    .text(`Eingelöste Commitments`)
            });

    }, [data, groups, height, width, selectedOption3]);


    return <svg ref={svgRef}/>;
}

export default CommitmentsBar;
```

Comment: what i found out aswell is that if a "loggedInUser" in the localStorage already exists it does the redirect just fine. it only doesnt works if there is no token at all in localStorage

example: if i write inTest1 which would be valid it doesnt do the redirect, but if i then refresh the site and write in Test1 again it does the redirect

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Submitting login form');
    console.log('Username: ' + username);

    // Check if user with entered username exists
    const userExists = fakeData.users.find((user) => user.username === username);

    if (userExists) {
        console.log('User exists. Redirecting to /');
        navigate('/');
        window.location.reload();
        localStorage.setItem('loggedInUser', username); // Set username in localStorage

    } else {
        // Clear username
        setUsername('');
        console.log('User does not exist.');
        // Handle invalid username case (display error message, etc.)
    }
};
```

adding a reload after the navigate did the job

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you not to make the `loggedInUser` validation in the Router of your application based on how you're handling the session of the user (which is the localStorage).

I'd just make the distinction inside a `useEffect` hook at the beginning of your ***Dashboard*** component like this:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser');
    
    if (!loggedInUser)
      navigate('login')
  }, [])
  
  return (
    //Your component code here
  )
}
```

But, ideally, I'd just implement a context in the application to handle data of the sort.